# Delegate specific part of build to slave

Tags: jenkins, hudson, distributed

I have a project where part of the build process is to create a native library on a remote machine. This is currently a manual process outside of the CI builds made by Jenkins.

The setup in question is that the Jenkins master server build a GIT based maven project, which has a dependency to a native library which can only be built on a specific machine. Jenkins can't compile this module, and because of this, it is currently a manual process.

I would like to install a Jenkins slave on the machine that creates the native library, and returns the compiled files to the Jenkins master, without handling any other parts of the build.

I am having trouble figuring out if this is even possible. The number of articles i have found on the subject discusses Jenkins slaves as a means of distributing the build, but i want the slave to take responsibility for a small part of the build process, and nothing else. The Jenkins master should just send the build request to the slave and wait for the result, instead of trying to compile the code itself.

Comment: You should extract the native library build as a separate job. Then you could tie the job to a particular slave.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it is indeed possible to delegate specific jobs to slaves?

Answer (score 3):

I do exactly the same. My setup, very similar to what Mark O'Connor and gaige are advising, and I am using the [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin).

- job A: produces a zip file on a Mac
- job B, runs on slave B - Windows machine, takes the zip as input and produces an MSI

Here's the important part in the config of job B:

1. restrict the job B on the proper slave using labels

   [image: restrict the job B on the proper slave using labels]
2. make sure job B happens after job A

   [image: make sure job B happens after job A]
3. make sure artifacts from job A are sent to job B before your build

   [image: make sure artifacts from job A are sent to job B]
4. build your stuff
5. archive artifacts produced by job B

   [image: archive artifacts produced by job B]

Answer (score 2):

Delegating part of a job to a slave is something that would have to be done external to Jenkins, for example, using ssh.

However, as @kan indicates, you most likely want to extract the native library build as a separate job and then have that job execute on a particular slave, or any slave that meets a specific criteria.

To do this, my suggestion would be to use `Labels` in the node configurations to determine which slaves can be used for building that particular job.

In `Jenkins > nodes > <slave node>`, use the `Labels` property to set one-word labels that indicate your specific requirements, such as the OS or processor type.

Then, in the jobs that are node-specific, check `Restrict where this project can be run` and set the `Label Expression` to something that meets your criteria.   If the criteria is simple, it will just be a single word, if you need a boolean, you can use those as well (such as `OSX&&Lion` in our case).

I believe this is all in the standard version of Jenkins, without need for a special plugin.  Leave me a comment if it isn't and I'll try and diagnose which plugin enables this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is problem is solved by using a binary repository manager to centralize your software artifacts. Personally I use [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), but it could be something as dumb as a remote file system.

The idea is to publish the built artifact after each Jenkins job (if you don't like Nexus, you could use one of the [Publish over](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+...) plugins) and retrieve it as a build dependency in the next job.

This approach means it longer matters where the build executes, and has the added advantage of decoupling the build of each module component.

Comment: There's also direct support for pulling artifacts from prior build stages using the Jenkins Copy Artifacts plugin without having to use a remote repository.

Comment: @gaige Good point. The Maven Deployment Linker plugin might also be an option. Never used it, but might be an interesting option when using Nexus as a repository: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Deployment+Linker

Comment: I already have a running nexus instance, so that shouldn't be a problem. But i am not quite sure i understand the solution? Are you proposing to trigger a build via SSH that automatically uploads to nexus after the build?

Comment: @MartinNielsen No. Ensure that your native library is built in a standalone fashion and pushed into Nexus upon completion. Other builds would then pull this down as a transtitive dependency. The whole point is to make sure that it no longer matters where each job runs. It is associated with the slave node that is suitable..... Now in terms of the end-to-end solution. Assuming you're using Maven, it will automatically rebuild projects when one project depends on the snapshot revision of another. This is really useful during development when multiple teams are collaborating with each other.